# Will weak convergence of continuous functions give a continuous function?

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, skorohod-space

Assume that $P_n$ is a sequence of probability measures on $D[0,1]$ with the Skorohod topology. Assume that they converge weakly to a measure $P$. Let $C$ be the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$, if $P_n(C)=1$, is it then the case that $P(C)=1$?

Comment: What does "the probability that each $P_n$ takes a continuous function is 1" mean?

Comment: @Jose27 It was a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: Consider piecewise linear functions converging to $\chi_{[1/2,1]}$.

Answer (score 3):

$P(C)\ge \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} P_n(C)=1$, since $C$ is a closed set in $D$.